# Which is a good approach for a isolated UI microservice integration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, microservices, vue-component, polymer-2.x

we are currently facing the challenge to integrate multiple API microservices and their corresponding UI into a web app.

We allready have some UI Solutions which we want to reuse and are searching for a good way to structure the client part.

The UI - microservice approach should divide the the javascript context so that they do not share the same window object.

I know about Polymerjs and thougth that within a script tag in a polymer component the window object is unique for that component but it seems that it is shared across all other polymer components. That is not a big problem if we all develop in a module base way but I know a view libaries which are not implemented as amd module. I belief that a Microservice-UI solution should have a good isolation against other components and their dependencies.

Another approach which I don't really prefer is a Iframe divided Webapp which has a dedicated Document Model for every View/Microservice.

Personaly I would prefer a solution with Vue.js but I can not find any samples which really divide the UI Parts of a Webapp into single views. I don not know how to load the components on demand.

So my questions:
Does anybody know a solution where webcomponents do not share the same window object? Is this possible?

Does anybody know a good approach to create microservice Ui components with vuejs.

What is your way to create a isolated UI Microservice WebApp?

Any suggestions regarding UI Microservice approaches are welcome!

Comment: found a similar question on stackexchange https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340939/microservice-at-a-frontend-level/349132#349132